# Distance between foundation stone and western wall

Tags: talmud-gemara, beis-hamikdash, shiurim-measurements, kotel-western-wall

What is the distance between the foundation stone and the western wall? Does the Talmud or anything say anything about the distance?

Comment: You can probably [measure it](https://www.google.com/maps)

Comment: The Dome of the Rock wasn't built until the late 7th century - after the period of the Talmud, so the Talmud doesn't mention it at all. Do you mean the foundation stone itself or the dome?